# How to dynamically create buttons from Json string

Tags: java, android, json

I parsed JSON data from URL into a list and now I want to create buttons with every item of the list, but I can't figured out how to do this. I'm not sure if the list is the best idea, but I this was the solution I found online.

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String TAG = SecondActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private ListView lv;

    private static String url = "https://ggysqqcz.p51.rt3.io/available-remotes/TV";

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        contactList = new ArrayList<>();

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        new GetContacts().execute();

    }


    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SecondActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    JSONArray remotes = jsonObj.getJSONArray("remotes");

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < remotes.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = remotes.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = c.getString("id");


                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();


                        contact.put("id", id);

                        contactList.add(contact);
                    }
                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }

            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();


            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(

                    SecondActivity.this, contactList,
                  R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"id"}, new int[]{button1});

            lv.setAdapter(adapter);


        }
    }

public void onClickButton1(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ThirdActivity.class));
    }
}
```

This shows all the buttons, but obviously they all do the same thing when clicked because I have only button1. How can I make all the buttons do different activities?

Comment: What do you want each button to do differently?

Comment: I want to execute a different function for each button

Comment: Please elaborate. What specific differences are there between two of the buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to suggest creating a custom adapter for your `ListView` which will have an `onClick` function for your button and based on the position of that item in your `ListView`, you can implement different actions in your `onClick` function. Hence I would like to suggest an adapter like the following.

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    private int resourceLayout;
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Contact> contacts;

    public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Contact> contacts) {
        super(context, resource, items);
        this.resourceLayout = resource;
        this.mContext = context;
        this.contacts = contacts;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            v = vi.inflate(resourceLayout, null);
        }

        Item p = getItem(position);

        if (p != null) {
            Button btn = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.button1);

            if (btn != null) {
                btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if(position == 1) implementSomethingFor1();
                        else if (position == 2) implementSomethingFor2();
                        // ... Define the other implementations
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        return v;
    }
}
```

And then use the adapter like the following.

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
ListAdapter customAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, contactList);
lv.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

Please note that this is not an exact implementation. You should modify your custom adapter so that it serves your purpose.

Comment: There is a problem with super(context, resource, items)

Comment: This should be a list instead of a `HashMap`, my bad. You might consider changing your map to an `ArrayList` as well, which is more logical I think.

Comment: It compiles, but the buttons don't appear :(

Comment: I think you do not have anything in your `ArrayList` then. Please make sure you have all your contacts in the `ArrayList` which is being passed to the adapter.

Comment: ListView is deprecated and should be avoided unless you have very old project to maintain. Never use ListView, RecyclerView should be used instead

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

1. Check the `view` parameter to determine what to do. You can use `getTag()` and `setTag()` to provide custom data on each button.
2. Create a custom adapter by extending `SimpleAdapter`.  Override createView() and bindView() in order to provide custom behavior for each button, such as adding a different OnClickListener object to each button
3. Set the `OnItemClickListener` for the `ListView`. This provides a parameter for which position in the list view was clicked. You can use that to determine what to do or what data to pass to the new activity. You will likely want to use `getItem()` from your adapter to get the data for the current row.

Comment: Thank you! I tried the third option. This is the code i wrote: lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) { String item = (String) lv.getItemAtPosition(position); } }); The problem is that I want to do something like this: new HandShakingTask().execute("qkwyoxlw.p50.rt3.io/volumeup"); when the first button is pressed and i don't know how :(

Comment: @PenaRoxana You can put that line in your listener. If it needs to be different for each button, you can use either options 1 or 2 or call `getItem()` on your adapter.

Answer (score 1):

try 
lv.setonitemclicklisnter, this will create a method which will allow you to click on each and every item, you can write for example A Toast message inside this method so when you click on an item a Toast message will pop up.

Comment: Thank you! I did this and it worked. The problem is that I want to execute a different task (like new HandShakingTask().execute() for example) for every button pressed